# how to get the result returned with conditions and assert the correct value

Tags: assert, assertion, assertj

i have written codes to assert the value stored from database.

```
//SQL statement
String dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM public.test where testId = 'default'/


//Connect to PostgresSQL, global variable is stored at profile
List results = CustomKeywords.'test.database.getPostgresSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString2 , GlobalVariable.dbUsername2 , GlobalVariable.dbPassword2 ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver2 ,dbQuery2 )
println(results)


//print the "test_info" column
String test_info = results.get(0).get('test_info')
println(test_info)

//convert to json format and verify result
def test_infojson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new String(test_info))
println('Database test_info response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(test_infojson)))
```

the result returned is:

```
{
    "testId": "default",
    "testLines": [
        {
            "testId": "TC-1",
            "name": "a",
            "isDeleted": true
        },
        {
            "testId": "TC-1",
            "name": "b",
            "isDeleted": false
        },
                {
            "testId": "TC-2",
            "name": "c",
            "isDeleted": true
        },
        {
            "testId": "TC-2",
            "name": "d",
            "isDeleted": false
        }
    ],
}
```

then i use assertion:

```
assertThat(test_infojson.testLines[0].name).isEqualTo("b")
```

this assertion is wrong, because there is 2 testId in the result, one isDeleted = true, another one false.

what should be the right assertion, to get the testLines which "testId": "TC-1" and "isDeleted": false
so the assert value is "name": "b"

i am using org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*
any other assert class is fine.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON assertions, I recommend using https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit